# Format the parsed csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, quotes

I have a csv file with the following format

`21/10/2017 0:00;123,85;88,8`

and i use the command to parse it

```
with open('parseme.csv') as csv_file:
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

So I get the values as

```
['21/10/2017 0:00;123', '85;88', '8']
```

The problem is I want the value after the date to be altogether because I cannot convert it to integer due to the quote characters in the middle before and after comma. How can I achieve to import it as it was in the CSV, like this:

```
['21/10/2017 0:00', '123,85', '88,8']
```

Comment: If you want it as a single string, why use csv at all?

Comment: Do you understand that the quote characters in the output are not actually part of your output? That's just how Python prints out a list of strings.

Comment: Fix the delimiter and the `csv` module will do the conversion for you. Which, I assume, is the reason you used that package in the first place

Comment: Did you mean `['21/10/2017 0:00', '123,85', '88,8']`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't think that's what OP wants but I also don't see why they would want is as `['21/10/2017 0:00;123,85;88,8']` They maybe meant: `['21/10/2017', '0:00;123,85;88,8']`

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's the output he'd get using the semicolon as delimiter. His code, however, uses the default delimiter, which is a comma. Hence the semicolon in the numbers and the impossibility to convert to numbers

Comment: Yes ['21/10/2017 0:00', '123,85', '88,8'] is what I mean. I added the question mark but after that I get
this is time: 0:00'
this is the day: ['21 so I still get characters I don't want. I want to make 21 day an integer, and python interprets the [' also, so I am getting an error. I want to ommit [' from this and get only the 21

Comment: @Petar, they'd want it the way I wrote it. It's a time stamp, which should include a space, and some numbers in a European locale.

Comment: @Gphilo. I understand the problem. I'm just trying to figure out what OP is thinking. FWIW, I think your answer is the correct one and Petar has no idea what's going on.

Comment: I added a delimiter and returned me ['22/10/2017 12:30', '13,91', '87,5'] but when I split this python returns me the value as ['22 as the date and '13 not 22 and 13... How can I dispose these extra characters and convert the number to integer for example?

Comment: @Cheetara please let me know if my edit is acceptable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the edit, it is corrected also at the first post now! :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to get the csv fields by splitting on the actual delimiter you're using (which is a semicolon, not a comma):

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
```

The result of iterating on `reader` now will be a series of lists of strings, looking like the following:

```
['21/10/2017 0:00', '123,85', '88,8']
```

(**Note:** this is the python representation for strings, **the `'` characters are not actually part of the data**)

Now, to get to the actual numbers, you need to turn those strings to values.
The second and the third are more or less straightforward, *but you need to take care of that comma*. The value you have is using a locale in which decimal values are separated by a comma, python expects a dot. So, we can convert them as follows (Let `line` be one line from the `reader`):

```
second_number = float(l[1].replace(',','.'))
third_number = float(l[2].replace(',','.'))
```

For the date the thing is more complicated. Assuming you're just interested in the numbers in the date and not a full conversion to some `datetime` value, this is what you could do:

```
date, time = line[0].split(' ') #separate "21/10/2017" from "0:00"
day, month, year = [int(v) for v in date.split('/')]
hour, minute = [int(v) for v in time.split(':')]
```

I hope this is clear enough and matching what you need

Comment: This will split by `;` meaning the output will be `['21/10/2017 0:00', '123,85', '88,8']` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: From the wording of the question, I believe what the OP wants is to parse the *data* in the csv, which this does. I do understand that the literal interpretation of the question is "how do I read a file line-by-line", but I believe this is not what the OP actually wants

Comment: I added the question mark but after that I get this is time: 0:00' this is the day: ['21 so I still get characters I don't want. I want to make 21 day an integer, and python interprets the [' also, so I am getting an error. I want to ommit [' from this and get only the 21

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Added the question mark"?

Comment: I added a delimiter and returned me ['22/10/2017 12:30', '13,91', '87,5']  but when I split this python returns me the value as ['22 as the date and '13 not 22 and 13... How can I dispose these extra characters andconvert the number to integer for example?

Comment: Ok, one step back. Of all those numbers, *which* one is the one you want to get?

Comment: Just the numbers! I get numbers with symbols, I want to get rid of the symbols and keep the number.

Comment: Ok, let me edit the answer to make it as clear as I can

Comment: @Cheetara. I think you need to look into locales. your data appears to be in a European locale, where dates are D/M/Y and the decimal separator is a comma. At the same time, use one of the built in date parsing functions.

Comment: @GPhilo Yes please, because the reading succeded but after that when I split on the comma I get funny results, numbers with quotes in front or after... I want to keep only the numbers!

Comment: @Cheetara how about now?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done :)

Comment: @GPhilo Thank you, it is very clear now. But will this work if some values don't have a comma as a separator? let's say if Ihave a value as ['21/10/2017 0:00', '123', '88']

Comment: Glad to hear it's clear :) Yes, this will work in that case too. `replace` searches for a string and replaces it with another. If the string is not there, nothing is changed

Comment: @GPhilo This was great, thank you so much, it worked perfectly :-)

Comment: Great to hear ;) If you don't mind, and the problem is solved, please mark the question as answered :)